# How to separate target numbers from text using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
EX/
CLIENTS INCOME DETAILS ARE AS FOLLOWS,

 - NET INCOME FROM WOOD SUPPLYING BUSINESS- RS 60,000/-
 - INCOME FROM HIRING THE VEHICLES- RS 20,000/-
 - TOTAL INCOME- RS 80,000/-
```

I only need to separate Total income only. final output should be 80000
how can i get this number using sql in sql server 2016?

Comment: Is this 1 row, or are they 3 different rows? What have you tried already?

Comment: check out this link to know more on how to improve question(https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: it has one column and the text including in one row.

Comment: CLIENTS INCOME DETAILS ARE AS FOLLOWS,NET INCOME FROM WOOD SUPPLYING BUSINESS- RS 60,000/-,INCOME FROM HIRING THE VEHICLES- RS 20,000/-,TOTAL INCOME- RS 80,000/-

Comment: i need to separate only total income as 80000 from this text and number field

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
SELECT CustomerName, (NetIncome + VehicleIncome) AS 'TotalIncome'
FROM Client_Income
GROUP BY CustomerName
ORDER BY CustomerName
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a table named ClientIncome with three rows named Customer, NetIncome, and VehicleIncome, the following query should do what you want:

```
SELECT Customer, NetIncome + VehicleIncome
FROM ClientIncome
```

It'll return a table with two rows, the first being the Customer and the second being the sum of the two incomes.

---

EDIT: Breaking number out of string

If you're using SQL Server 2016, and the column with the information string is called 'info', you can try this (I don't have access to a sql server so I can't test it myself):

```
SELECT Cast( Substring(info,
                 Charindex('RS', info, 3) + 3
                 Len(info) - Charindex('RS', info, 3) - 2)
       As Int )
FROM ClientInfo
```

---

*DISCLAIMER*

Forgive any weirdness or wrong information as I did all of the research for this from my phone, so it may not be as thorough as I would like it to be. Take this answer with a pinch of salt.

Comment: actually i want, separate the income value from the text field, text field will contain text and numbers

Comment: @YohanDe is it a single column with the whole string, or multiple rows with a string each?

Comment: @YohanDe check out the edits to my answer. Hopefully it does what you want.

Comment: (CLIENTS INCOME DETAILS ARE AS FOLLOWS,NET INCOME FROM WOOD SUPPLYING BUSINESS- RS 60,000/-,INCOME FROM HIRING THE VEHICLES- RS 20,000/-,TOTAL INCOME- RS 80,000) this is a text field including in one column and one row, all i need to do is separate total income value from text field

Comment: @YohanDe did you try the new part of my answer? That should get you the number from that text field.

Comment: I cant find your answer here

Comment: @YohanDe that's strange. Well anyways, try "SELECT Cast( Substring(info, Charindex('RS', info, 3) + 3, Len(info) - Charindex('RS', info, 3) - 2) AS INT ) FROM ClientInfo", replacing 'info' with the name of the text column and 'ClientInfo' with the name of the table.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE('80,000/-','/-',''),',','')`